# Flatten Array of Objects based on nested Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I have this Array of Objects that I would need to transform into a flat Array of Objects. It looks as follows.

```
const points = [
    {
        highlights: [
            {
                title: 'Title 1',
                description: 'Description 1',
                x: 111,
                y: 222,
            },
            {
                title: 'Title 2',
                description: 'Description 2',
                x: 111,
                y: 222,
            },
        ],
        width: 1108,
        height: 1528,
        relativePath: '/image_01.jpg',
    },
    {
        highlights: [
            {
                title: 'Title 3',
                description: 'Description 3',
                x: 199,
                y: 411,
            },
            {
                title: 'Title 4',
                description: 'Description 4',
                x: 213,
                y: 1132,
            },
        ],
        width: 1108,
        height: 1528,
        relativePath: '/image_02.jpg',
    },
];
```

I would like each points.highlights[x] to have its own index so the Array would look as such:

```
[
    {
        title: 'Title 1',
        description: 'Description 1',
        x: 111,
        y: 222,
        width: 1108,
        height: 1528,
        relativePath: '/image_01.jpg',
    },
    {
        title: 'Title 2',
        description: 'Description 2',
        x: 111,
        y: 222,
        width: 1108,
        height: 1528,
        relativePath: '/image_01.jpg',
    },
    {
        title: 'Title 3',
        description: 'Description 3',
        x: 111,
        y: 222,
        width: 1108,
        height: 1528,
        relativePath: '/image_02.jpg',
    },
    {
        title: 'Title 4',
        description: 'Description 4',
        x: 111,
        y: 222,
        width: 1108,
        height: 1528,
        relativePath: '/image_02.jpg',
    },
];
```

I believe `flatMap` is part of the solution but then I am unsure how exactly I would be able to retain the other properties (`width`, `height`, `relativePath`).
I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply:

```js
const points = 
  [ { highlights: 
      [ { title: 'Title 1', description: 'Description 1', x: 111, y: 222 } 
      , { title: 'Title 2', description: 'Description 2', x: 111, y: 222 } 
      ] 
    , width        : 1108
    , height       : 1528
    , relativePath : '/image_01.jpg'
    } 
  , { highlights: 
      [ { title: 'Title 3', description: 'Description 3', x: 199, y: 411  } 
      , { title: 'Title 4', description: 'Description 4', x: 213, y: 1132 } 
      ] 
    , width        : 1108
    , height       : 1528
    , relativePath : '/image_02.jpg'
    } 
  ] 

const result = points.reduce((res,{highlights,...plus})=>
  {
  highlights.forEach(hl=> res.push({...hl,...plus}))
  return res
  }
  ,[])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using flatMap:

```
points.flatMap(point => 
    point.highlights.flatMap(obj => {
        let temp = { ... point, ... obj };
        delete temp["highlights"];
        return temp;
    })
);
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer - unfortunately, I can't access lodash for this.